# Magento not showing admin panel after extension installation

Tags: php, xml, magento, livechat

I have installed the extension.

But after installation it is not showing admin panel.

Below is my error & warning log which is coming on zopim Live chat integration using magento.

```
2016-01-12T05:36:06+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:39:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:39:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:40:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:40:21+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:42:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:42:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:42:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:42:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:13+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:32+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:44:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Zopim_Livechat_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/html/magento/includes/src:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-01-12T05:49:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-12T05:49:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-12T05:49:16+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-12T05:49:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-12T05:49:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-12T05:49:31+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-12T05:50:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-12T05:50:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;reference name=&quot;left&quot;&gt;  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
2016-01-12T05:50:22+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^  in /var/www/html/magento/includes/src/__default.php on line 29213
```

Comment: Please provide more infos, what extension are you trying to install? What is your project about?

Comment: @FabioBerger extension is 'live chat' ..

Comment: give more details about your issue. set tag for technology

Comment: Failure to follow proper procedures for Magento module installation leading to cache and compiler code store corruption. To recover, Shut off compiler, clear cache. Search here and in magento.stackexchage for how to do that, it's a question that's been answered multiple times. Once you have Magento running, try recompiling, if it breaks, turn off the compiler as it's incompatible with your Zopim enabling third party Magento Module..

Comment: clear your cache and check for the permissions first. if all are set then there might be some issue in extension installation. install the extension again

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge there is a issue with compilation tool of magento. You must disable compilation process before installing any extension. So first uninstall the extension. Then go through below steps.

1. Login to magento admin and goto "System->Tool->Compilation" And disable compilation.
2. Now clear cache and install the extension again.
3. Logout from admin panel.
4. Now your extension should work. You can re-enable compilation process after that.